# Can't check if the "Extension installed" page was opened

Tags: puppeteer

I have an extension, which has a listener for the **chrome.runtime.onInstalled** event, that opens a new page when the extension is installed. I can see it happening in regular Chrome and in puppeteer also, using the config below:

```js
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      `--disable-extensions-except=${extensionPath}`,
      `--load-extension=${extensionPath}`
    ]
  })
  page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setViewport({
    width: config.viewport.width,
    height: config.viewport.height
  })
```

But I can't seem to get the data for this new tab, which should be returned by this command:

```js
    let pages = await browser.targets()
    pages.forEach( (v, i) => {
      console.log(i, v._targetInfo)
    })
```

Which only returns this:

```js
  console.log test/installedExtension.test.js:49
    0 { targetId: '2E60BA3854355C415D48D89AA65727BC',
      type: 'page',
      title: '',
      url: 'about:blank',
      attached: false,
      browserContextId: '11F90429E632C8BC5C0073B1B74D0497' }

  console.log test/installedExtension.test.js:49
    1 { targetId: '416b3c97-04e7-4042-9401-d5ea7880bf22',
      type: 'browser',
      title: '',
      url: '',
      attached: true }

  console.log test/installedExtension.test.js:49
    2 { targetId: 'A8AA1B73923E934D284BD65CBF779956',
      type: 'background_page',
      title: 'Some Random Title',
      url:
       'chrome-extension://kmendfapggjehodndflmmgagdbamhnfd/_generated_background_page.html',
      attached: false,
      browserContextId: '11F90429E632C8BC5C0073B1B74D0497' }

  console.log test/installedExtension.test.js:49
    3 { targetId: '0A42832C4BD6539557765E8E99F113ED',
      type: 'background_page',
      title: 'My Extension Title',
      url:
       'chrome-extension://kpepplbhmfgaiibhacpojdokimblkbnh/src/background.html',
      attached: false,
      browserContextId: '11F90429E632C8BC5C0073B1B74D0497' }

  console.log test/installedExtension.test.js:49
    4 { targetId: 'C5B3440C60F001E559B01F364093F6CF',
      type: 'page',
      title: '',
      url: 'about:blank',
      attached: true,
      browserContextId: '11F90429E632C8BC5C0073B1B74D0497' }
```

Although it brings me the info about the extension's background HTML, I need to get the opened tab, to do some assertions.

Does anybody have any ideas on this matter?

Comment: So, you can see the tab, but it's not in the list? Are you sure that you are not running that loop too early (before the extension has opened the tab)?

Comment: I don't think so, I've tried to make the process sleep for a couple of seconds, and still nothing. Almost seems that this new tab is opened in a different process

Comment: Sounds like a bug then. You might want to open an issue in the github repository.